# How to Increase Scale(In General) In Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to be able to increase the scale of the IntelliJ IDEA to increase the size of everything(text, folders etc), not just font size, because everything looks very small on high resolution screens(MacBook Pro Retina). I know it can be done by navigating **Help / Edit Custom VM Options** but forgot the option to increase scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-192797.

You can either increase the default font size (Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance > Override default font) so that UI scaling factor is calculated from it or add -Dide.ui.scale=2.0 in Help | Edit Custom VM Options.

Comment: Yes, that was the option I was looking for! Now folders look much better if I make the scale **1.25**